# MVC Action has the same name, but diffrent controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Routemap structure:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "NaturalStonesDetails",
            url: "{lang}/natural-stones/{title}-{id}",
            defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "NaturalStones", action = "Details" }
        );    

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProductCategorieList",
            url: "{lang}/products/{title}-{id}",
            defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Product", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Link structure:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { title = stoneguide.com.Models.DealerProduct.GetTitleUrlFormat(items.CategoryName), id = Convert.ToInt32(items.ID) })" style="padding:2px;">
```

Problem:

When I click on the link, go to the product page, which should go to NaturalStones page. I can not solve this problem, a kind.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your routing is quite neat and should work just fine with the code provided. I think you just got confused by which controller to use. So

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { title = "mytitle", id = "myid" })
```

returns `/en/products/mytitle-myid` which the routing correctly recognises as the request to Product controller, Index action with two parameters.

On the other hand

```
@Url.Action("Details", "NaturalStones", new { title = "mytitle", id = "myid" });
```

generates `/en/natural-stones/mytitle-myid` which is interpreted as request to NaturalStones, Details action with two parameters, and that's probably the one you want to use.

On the side note, providing `title` and `id` for Product, Index action is a bit awkward. By convention Index action usually returns a list of items, hence a reference to a specific id seems to be out of place. You might consider changing your routing to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NaturalStonesDetails",
    url: "{lang}/natural-stones/{title}-{id}",
    defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "NaturalStones", action = "Details" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductCategorieList",
    url: "{lang}/products",
    defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Product", action = "Index" }
);
```

and then have controllers as follow:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
public class NaturalStonesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(string title, string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```